# What is the purpose of the mysterious "wind" or "fan"-like platform outside Bazaar?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

Around the Bazaar, there is a flat indentation in the grass that looks like it has some sort of purpose, but I'm coming up on the end of the game and can't find anything to do with it.

It's basically a white square with rounded edges with a green clover-like imprint on it.  It looks almost like a fan.  Here's some pictures:

[image]

Does it have any purpose?  There are none other like it in the game that I have found.

Comment: Any chance you could take a screen shot of this?

Comment: I'll try to take a screenshot later today when I get home.  I've wondered about it for a while but it just popped into my mind here at work.

Comment: I've wondered about that, too, but I never found a use for it.

Comment: I've added a screen shot.  Hopefully, this is what you're talking about.

Comment: @splatteredbits: I've added a cleaner screen capture.  :D

Comment: Thanks guys!  Yeah thats the platform I was talking about.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They serve no purpose, they are just merely the skylights for the houses they are above.  Notice at night, it is a lot brighter from the outside.  That's because of the lights inside shining out.  If you look from the inside, it should be pretty clear that they are skylights:

[image: inside view at night]
*Skylights at night from inside **Kukiel's** house*

They are probably all designed that way to go with the **Skyloft** theme of having fans (and fan-shaped objects) everywhere.

Comment: Ahhhhh I see!  That makes total sense, thanks!  I'm a little disappointed there was no sidequest-related function though.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't finished the game.  In fact, I'm not even close.  I'll go out on a limb and say **it is purely decorational** and serves no purpose in the game other than to make the game look lived-in.